# Scraping with Python BeautifulSoup two prices

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

i'm currently working on scraping this website:

`https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/oficinas-suministros-papeleria-papel-en-aragua/resma-carta-alpes`

i've been successful until i apply the "text" attribute to the decimal price variable.

this is the code i've been using:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/oficinas-suministros-papeleria-papel-en-aragua/resma-carta-alpes'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item__info-container"})
for container in containers:
    title_container = container.a.text.strip()
    price_container_fraction = container.find("span" ,{"class":"price__fraction"}).text
    price_container_decimal = container.find("span" ,{"class":"price__decimals"})
    print(title_container)
    print(price_container_fraction)
    print(price_container_decimal)
```

this is the html ad block:

```
<div class="item__info-container ">
    <div class="item__info item--hide-right-col ">
        <h2 class="item__title list-view-item-title"> <a class="item__info-title" href="https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ve/MLV-523616759-resma-tamano-carta-marca-alpes-caja-_JM"> <span class="main-title"> Resma Tamaño Carta Marca Alpes Caja </span> </a></h2>
        <div class="price__container">
            <div class="item__price "> <span class="price__symbol">Bs.</span> <span class="price__fraction">4</span> <span class="price__decimals">50</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item__stack_column">
            <div class="item__stack_column__info item__only-status">
                <div class="stack_column_item status">
                    <div class="item__status">
                        <div class="item__condition"> 2 vendidos </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stack_colum_right without-attributes without-reviews">
            <div class="stack_column_right__bottom "> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

i need to gather the 2 elements of the price and then add them but no luck. any help?

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `price_decimals` span isn't always populated, `find` returns `None` when this occurs. I've added the following to your code and tested it, it produces what I've guessed is your required output. The if conditional checks for `None` if that's True it sets `price_container_decimal` to `00`, if it's not it sets it to the text property value of the span.

```
price_container_decimal = container.find("span" ,{"class":"price__decimals"})    
if price_container_decimal == None:
    price_container_decimal = "00"
else:
    price_container_decimal = container.find("span" ,{"class":"price__decimals"}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

price_container_decimal is printing the entire html content, add .text to print the decimal value only.

```
price_container_decimal = container.find("span" ,{"class":"price__decimals"}).text
```